# Get NSURLConnection associated with an NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I've been running through [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial) from Ray Wenderlich around custom NSURLProtocols. I have a scenario where I'm intercepting particular NSURLRequests (call them 'request a') and firing off another request ('request b'). For the scenarios where this second request (b) fails, i want to be able to cancel the original request (a), at the moment it is just timing out after a period of time, but I want a bit more control and immediately fail it.

Within the custom NSURLProtocol I'm creating a new NSURLConnection for request b using the intercepted NSURLRequest (request a), but does anyone know if it's possible to get a reference to the original NSURLConnection which fired that request a? This would allow me to cancel it if the subsequent request b call failed?

Edit:

None of the NSURLConnection delegate methods will give me access to the originating NSURLConnection object, since self.connection in my example will relate to 'request b', not the originating request

See example delegate methods below:

```
- (void)startLoading {
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:self.request 
delegate:self];
}

- (void)stopLoading {
    [self.connection cancel];
     self.connection = nil;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code snippet for your implementation?

Comment: *This tutorial* is almost 4 years old and the API is outdated.

Comment: Does that mean it is not possible using NSURLConnection? I'm aware NSURLSession is the favoured approach, but was just following through the tutorial - I'm not sure if they have a revised edition using NSURLSession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you communicate with the original connection or session by calling methods in the `NSURLProtocolClient` protocol on whatever object is in your `NSURLProtocol` subclass's `client` property.  The object itself might be part of the `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` machinery, depending on how the request was initiated, but either way, you call the same methods.

For example, you probably want to call this one:

```
- (void)URLProtocol:(NSURLProtocol *)protocol 
   didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

See Apple's [NSURLProtocolClient Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocolclient?language=objc) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, turns out i was having an issue with threading. It turned out my call was getting made on a different thread to what the original request was fired on, so even though my call was failing and going this delegate method, the original request was timing out, and not failing immediately, i should have spotted this straight away from the Thread debugger view in XCode, will know for the next time! :) Thanks!